# How to rotate an object around one of its local axis in DirectX11

Tags: c++, matrix, rotation, directx-11

I want to rotate an object around one of its local axis. In my case the Y-axis.
The object has its own world matrix that is initialized like this:

```
XMFLOAT4X4 newInstance;

// Construct matrix
XMStoreFloat4x4( &newInstance.worldMatrix, XMMatrixScaling( scale.x, scale.y, scale.z ) *
                 XMMatrixRotationRollPitchYaw( XMConvertToRadians( rotation.x ),
                                               XMConvertToRadians( rotation.y ),
                                               XMConvertToRadians( rotation.z ) ) *
                    XMMatrixTranslation( translation.x, translation.y, translation.z ) ) ;

// Add new instance to collection
mInstanceData.push_back( newInstance );
```

My end goal is to rotate my object based on input from a gamepad.

I **don't** have a "math-heavy" background so please bear with me on this one. 
I'm familiar with the importance of order when multiplying matrices (Scale * Rotation * Translation). I've tried several approaches and all fail on me.

### 1st approach

```
// Create rotation matrix
XMMATRIX rotationMatrix = XMMatrixRotationY( XMConvertToRadians( angle ) );

// Multiply with old matrix AND store back to the old matrix
XMStoreFloat4x4( &newInstance.worldMatrix, XMLoadFloat4X4( &newInstance.worldMatrix ) * rotationMatrix );
```

This results in the object rotating around the world Y-axis and **not** its local axis.

### 2nd approach

I figured that I need to find my local Y-axis. Perhaps extracting it out of my existing world matrix? I found [this](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/322275-how-get-local-xyz-axis-from-world-matrix/) post where someone explains that
you **can** indeed extract all the local axis of an object from its world matrix.

> A | 1 0 0 0 | 
>   B | 0 1 0 0 | 
>   C | 0 0 1 0 | 
>   D | 0 0 0 1 | 
>   ----x y z w
>
> Here, the first three values in row A are your local X-axis = (1,0,0)
>   first three values in row B are your local Y-axis = (0,1,0)
>   and first three values in row C are your local z-axis = (0,0,1).

So I went about extracting the Y-axis from the object world matrix.

```
// Construct axis
XMVECTOR axis =  XMVectorSet( mInstanceData[0].worldMatrix._21, mInstanceData[0].worldMatrix._22, mInstanceData[0].worldMatrix._23, 0 );

// Create rotation matrix based on axis
XMMATRIX rotationMatrix = XMMatrixRotationAxis( axis ,XMConvertToRadians( angle) );

// Multiply with old matrix AND store back to the old matrix
XMStoreFloat4x4( &mInstanceData[0].worldMatrix, XMLoadFloat4x4( &mInstanceData[0].worldMatrix ) * rotationMatrix );
```

This approach also failed. The result of using [XMMatrixRotationAxis](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.directx_sdk.matrix.xmmatrixrotationaxis%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the object rotating around and axis from the world origin to the specified vector.

### 3rd approach

Then I thought that I could perhaps perform the rotation using the same technique I initialized the matrix with! This meant that I still needed to extract some current data from the objects world matrix. I found this:
[image]

So I tried to extract any relevant data from the current world matrix and construct new Scale, Rotation and Translation matrices, multiply them and store into the object world matrix.

```
// Extract scale and translation and construct new matrix
XMStoreFloat4x4( &mInstanceData[0].worldMatrix,  XMMatrixScaling( mInstanceData[0].worldMatrix._11, mInstanceData[0].worldMatrix._22, mInstanceData[0].worldMatrix._33 ) *
        XMMatrixRotationRollPitchYaw( 0.0f, XMConvertToRadians( angle ), 0.0f ) *
        XMMatrixTranslation( mInstanceData[0].worldMatrix._41, mInstanceData[0].worldMatrix._42, mInstanceData[0].worldMatrix._43 ) );
```

This resulted in the object just morphing itself into something unspeakable.

When all things fail you turn to stackoverlow.. Anyone out there with some insight to share? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIU, the 1st approach is correct, however, it seems that first you create a world matrix (hence each of your vertex is in world-space now) and then you apply the 'around-local-y-axis' transformation. IMO, you should first apply *XMMatrixRotationY( XMConvertToRadians( angle ) );* to vertexes in model-space and then construct World Matrix.